# How to reproduce this legend with multiple curves?

Tags: python, matplotlib, legend

I've been working hard on a package of functions for my work, and I'm stuck on a layout problem. Sometimes I need to work with a lot of columns subplots (1 row x N columns) and the standard matplotlib legend sometimes is not helpful and makes it hard to visualize all the data.

I've been trying to create something like the picture below. I already tried to create a subplot for the curves and another one for the legends (and display the x-axis scale as a horizontal plot). Also, I tried to spine the x-axis, but when I have a lot of curves plotted inside the same subplots the legend becomes huge.

The following image is from a software. I'd like to create a similar look. Notice that these legends are "static": it remains fixed independent of the zooming. Another observation is, I don't need all the ticks or anything like that.

[image]

What I'm already have is the following (the code is a mess, becouse I'm trying many different solutions and it is not organized nor pythonic yet.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
fig, ax = plt.subplots(1,2, sharey = True)

ax[0].semilogx(np.zeros_like(dados.Depth)+0.02, dados.Depth)
ax[0].semilogx(dados.AHT90, dados.Depth, label = 'aht90')

ax[0].set_xlim(0.2,2000)

ax[0].grid(True, which = 'both', axis = 'both')
axres1 = ax[0].twiny()
axres1.semilogx(dados.AHT90, dados.Depth, label = 'aht90')
axres1.set_xlim(0.2 , 2000)
axres1.set_xticks(np.logspace(np.log10(0.2),np.log10(2000),2))
axres1.spines["top"].set_position(("axes", 1.02))
axres1.get_xaxis().set_major_formatter(matplotlib.ticker.ScalarFormatter())
axres1.tick_params(axis='both', which='both', labelsize=6)
axres1.set_xlabel('sss')#, labelsize = 5)

axres2 = ax[0].twiny()
axres2.semilogx(dados.AHT10, dados.Depth, label = 'aht90')
axres2.set_xlim(0.2 , 2000)
axres2.set_xticks(np.logspace(np.log10(0.2),np.log10(2000),2))
axres2.spines["top"].set_position(("axes", 1.1))
axres2.get_xaxis().set_major_formatter(matplotlib.ticker.ScalarFormatter())
axres2.tick_params(axis='both', which='both', labelsize=6)
axres2.set_xlabel('aht10')#, labelsize = 5)
fig.show()
```

and the result is:

[image]

But well, I'm facing some issues on make a kind of make it automatic. If I add more curves, the prameter "set position" it is not practical to keep setting the position "by hand"

```
set_position(("axes", 1.02))
```

and another problem is, more curves I add, that kind of "legend" keep growing upward, and I have to adjust the subplot size with

```
fig.subplots_adjust(top=0.75)
```

And I'm also want to make the adjustment automatic, without keeping updating that parameter whenever I add more curves

Comment: As this is programming question, you might add the code you already tried. As you seem to be creating some functions to reuse, some simple test data to create an example would be very handy. Creating a plot like the image would involve quite some special purpose code, and probably would need to be adapted if the requirements change.  You should certainly think about writing very clear requirements. Note that StackOverflow is for answering programming related questions, it is not a programming service.

Comment: Thanks for you answar JohanC. But that'is exactly the problem. I'd like suggestions to solve that. I don't want a programming service. But I saw myself stucked and I don't have anything more than create subplots and plotting it. Gonna update it

Comment: It will be very hard to create something that is similar and general enough to serve multiple use cases. Especially without a very fixed list of requirements.

Comment: code updated right now